# How can I pass a variable to all the HttpResponse?

Tags: django, django-views

I am learning Django and I want to list in all my pages the categories, that are for example `categories = Category.objects.all()`, but I think it's very redundant to declare that variable in all my views and pass it in every HttpResponse. Is there any way to do it for all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add categories to all the pages it may be useful to write a custom template tag, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags